# weird problem with aspx page closing automatically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7

First I am new to the asp .net world and am trying to figure out a weird issue that I am having. Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

I have a page that has a form and on submit I launch another aspx file that exists in the same directory.

The problem is the aspx file is shown and the file closes immediately!. 
Howewever, the weird part is if I make any modifications to the aspx file and save it and then run my application it works fine ONLY THE FIRST TIME!? any subsequent submit actions launch the aspx page but then the aspx file immediately closes.

But after I make some modifications to the aspx file..(simple ones) it launches correctly the first time.

I realize that this is very little info to go on and I am not even sure if I have got my point across...but any suggestions on how to debug this will be helpful.

We are targetting .net version 4.0 and using IIS7. 
I am thinking that the asp worker process is doing something weird like checking for timestamps and closing it?! Not sure tho.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying the BROWSER is closing when you open the aspx page?

Comment: No not the browser, but the aspx page.

Comment: the aspx page that I launch on submit...I have the following code: <form method='POST' action='/mydirectory/testFolder/testpage.aspx' name='form1'>  testpage.aspx opens closes automatically.

Comment: What does it mean “a page closes”? You open a browser, go to a URL, the page is shown and then … what? The browser stays open, you say, so what does it display? Empty page? Another page? What is in the address bar?

Comment: Yes..sorry i should have been more clear...i guess its from staying up too late...Yes..onsubmit opens up a new Browser window opens the page inside it and then the browser closes...immediately.

Comment: @JohnFx...I apologize for not realizing your comment correctly..!! Yes the browser that hosts the page is closing.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net webforms don't use the form in quite the same way as regular HTML forms. All you need in your form tag is

```
<form runat="server">
```

If you want to pass the user onto another `aspx` page you can use the `Response` object:

```
Response.Redirect("~/pages/SomeOtherPage.aspx");
```

or (`Server.Transfer` - [read up on the differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28VS.90%29.aspx))
    Server.Transfer("~/pages/SomeOtherPage.aspx");

If you want to open a page in a new/pop-up window or similar you'll need to do so using JavaScript

`window.open('/pages/SomeOtherPage.aspx')` <sub>[There are overridden versions of this method]</sub>

You can use the forms `PostbackUrl` property too, but this will also keep the user in the same browser window. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx).

HTH